# Procfile for Heroku not working properly - Django using Waitress

Tags: python, django, heroku

Struggling to the Procfile I'm using for heroku working. Trying to learn how to get a basic django website up and running and have built something from scratch. I use windows on my PC to tinker around so decided on using waitress but perhaps gunicorn would be easier?

If I can't work it out I'll just use a template from heroku and build from that but I would rather not get rid of what i've done so far.

This is my directory structure.

```
Root +---
    .git
    Include
    Lib
    Scripts
    Scripts
    Static
    tcl
    src +---
        �   db.sqlite3
        �   manage.py
        �
        +---alex1
        �   �   forms.py
        �   �   settings.py
        �   �   urls.py
        �   �   wsgi.py
        �   �   __init__.py
        �   �
        �   +---__pycache__
        �           settings.cpython-36.pyc
        �           urls.cpython-36.pyc
        �           wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
        �           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
        �
        +---profiles
            �   admin.py
            �   apps.py
            �   forms.py
            �   models.py
            �   tests.py
            �   views.py
            �   __init__.py
            �
            +---migrations
            �   �   0001_initial.py
            �   �   0002_profile_description.py
            �   �   0003_auto_20170905_1654.py
            �   �   0004_auto_20170905_1659.py
            �   �   __init__.py
            �   �
            �   +---__pycache__
            �           0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
            �           0002_profile_description.cpython-36.pyc
            �           0003_auto_20170905_1654.cpython-36.pyc
            �           0004_auto_20170905_1659.cpython-36.pyc
            �           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
            �
            +---templates
            �       base.html
            �       contact.html
            �
            +---__pycache__
                    admin.cpython-36.pyc
                    forms.cpython-36.pyc
                    models.cpython-36.pyc
                    views.cpython-36.pyc
                    __init__.cpython-36.pyc
```

The error I'm receiving is this

```
2017-10-08T09:33:38.547463+00:00 app[web.1]: There was an exception (ModuleNotFoundError) importing your module.
2017-10-08T09:33:38.547464+00:00 app[web.1]: It had these arguments:
2017-10-08T09:33:38.547464+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. No module named 'profiles'
```

And this is my procfile.

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT profiles.wsgi:application
```

Thanks everyone - truly appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your wsgi.py file is not inside *src/profiles* is inside *src/alex1*. Also, waitress is not finding your app *profiles* because is not in the python path. I don't know if waitress has a parameter to add stuff into the PYTHONPATH (like *gunicorn --pythonpath*) but anyway you can do something like this:

```
web: PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)'/src' waitress-serve --port=$PORT alex1.wsgi:application
```

I've worked with waitress and I can't see the improvement of using it instead of gunicorn. Some people say it's more performant but in my experience it's just more annoying to use.

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thank you. If I use gunicorn, will it be fine considering i'm developing from windows? Cheers

Comment: Ouch! Right, you are using windows... no, you can't use gunicorn... Your choices are waitress (that's already working so I would keep it) or use gunicorn in Heroku and for local development use the manage.py runserver

Comment: Okay cool so I could use gunicorn as i'm not using it locally? Thanks mate